# bootable USB key cannot boot in legacy mode?

Tags: uefi, liveusb, unetbootin

I used the netbootin to generate a Mint 17.1 live USB on a EFI kubuntu system. It can be boot in computer with UEFI mode. However, if I change to legacy mode, the live USB cannot boot at all.

Is there any way to create a legacy mode compatible live USB?

Comment: Would you please tell us more about the specific hardware and BIOS you are using?

Comment: In theory, it should work; however, there are sometimes quirky incompatibilities between particular tools for creating bootable USB drives and particular firmware implementations. These can also interact with the OS/distribution in question. Thus, my recommendation is to try another tool. Also, in my experience, some brands of USB flash drives simply are not bootable on some computers. Thus, you might want to try a different USB flash drive.

Comment: @cxw GA-Z77-D3H